# How to dynamically set default value in `select` control

Tags: html, angular, typescript, html-select, angular-reactive-forms

I am subscribing to the HTTP server for the data to receive after which my `select` control gets loaded with the data by Angular framework.
My goal is to set the default value.
My default value consists of three values from the object I have received from the server separated by "/", so the HTML code looks like this:

```
<label>{{ functionStr }}</label>
<select #element formControlName="selectedUser" class="form-select" (change)="changeClient($event)">
    <option *ngFor="let account of accountsAvailable4Function">{{ account.firstName }}/{{ account.lastName }}/{{ account.email }}
    </option>
</select>
```

I have used the default value when initializing `FormGroup`:

```
var selected = this.accountsAvailable4Function[1].firstName+"/"+this.accountsAvailable4Function[1].lastName+"/"+this.accountsAvailable4Function[1].email
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      scheduledDate: ['', Validators.required],
      selectedUser: [selected, [Validators.required]],
    });
```

This throws an exception because my `accountsAvailable4Function` array is not initialized yet.

I tried to set it using the `FormGroup` control as below. This also does not work because I suspect that the control is not loaded yet:

```
var selected = this.accountsAvailable4Function[1].firstName+"/"+this.accountsAvailable4Function[1].lastName+"/"+this.accountsAvailable4Function[1].email
this.f['selectedUser'].setValue(selected);
```

Is there some event that I could listen to, to notify me when select control is loaded?

Appended:
Loading `accountsAvailable4Function` array:

```
this.accountService.getAll()
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe({
        next: (accounts: Account[]) => {
          accounts.forEach(account => {
            account.userFunctions.forEach(userFunc => {
              if(userFunc.userFunction == this.functionStr) {
                this.accountsAvailable4Function.push(account);
              }
            });
          });
          
          /* HTML select control selects by default first element - verify it*/
          this.selectedAccount = this.accountsAvailable4Function[0];
          this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.accountsSelected4Function);
          this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;

        },
        complete: () => {
          this.accountsLoaded = true;
          var selected = this.accountsAvailable4Function[1].firstName+"/"+this.accountsAvailable4Function[1].lastName+"/"+this.accountsAvailable4Function[1].email
          this.f['selectedUser'].setValue(selected);
        },
        error: error => {
          this.alertService.error(error);
          this.accountsLoaded = true;
        }
      });
```

Comment: Can you show you initialize `accountsAvailable4Function `? Is it from the observable?

Comment: Done. Under heading `Appended` in original question. Is is from Observable.

Comment: From what I see, you are missing the `value` attribute in option element. It should be: `<option *ngFor="let account of accountsAvailable4Function" [value]="account.firstName + '/' + account.lastName + '/' + account.email">{{ account.firstName }}/{{ account.lastName }}/{{ account.email }}</option>`

Comment: It worked (thank you) but how?. What is the `[value]` - I can't find on internet the meaning of it. Is that some sort of pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your current code, you are missing the `value` attribute for the `<option>` elements. This results that the `<option>` elements' value as the empty string as default. Thus you see the `<select>` element is not bonded with the default value.

You need to set the `value` attribute as mentioned to the `<option>` as [template expression `[]`](https://angular.io/guide/property-binding#binding-to-a-property).

```
<select #element formControlName="selectedUser" class="form-select" (change)="changeClient($event)">
  <option *ngFor="let account of accountsAvailable4Function" 
    [value]="account.firstName + '/' + account.lastName + '/' + account.email">
      {{ account.firstName }}/{{ account.lastName }}/{{ account.email }}
  </option>
</select>
```